# Differentiability of Function of Two Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, solution-verification

Define $g(x, y) := (|x| + |y|)^{1/2}$. Find those points in $\Bbb R^{2}$ at which $g$ is differentiable.

My Idea of a Solution:

In the $1^{st}$ Quadrant, $g(x,y)= (x + y)^{1/2}$, which is a composition of two differntiable functions and by Chain Rule, it is differentiable in $1^{st}$ Quadrant.

In the $2^{nd}$ Quadrant, $g(x,y)= (-x + y)^{1/2}$, which is a composition of two differntiable functions and by Chain Rule, it is differentiable in $2^{nd}$ Quadrant.

In the $3^{rd}$ Quadrant, $g(x,y)= (-x - y)^{1/2}$, which is a composition of two differntiable functions and by Chain Rule, it is differentiable in $3^{rd}$ Quadrant.

In the $4^{th}$ Quadrant, $g(x,y)= (x - y)^{1/2}$, which is a composition of two differntiable functions and by Chain Rule, it is differentiable in $4^{th}$ Quadrant.

So, it is differentiable in all of $\Bbb R^{2}$.

Is it correct? Please suggest if anything is wrong.

Comment: What about the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$?

Comment: You need to check the interfaces between the quadrants now. In fact, you can simply check if the derivatives coming from the different quadrants agree where they meet.

Comment: @mickep: It is differentiable on both those lines as well using the same argument as above, isn't it?

Comment: @aes: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Is the function $|x|$ differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$? Well for $x \geq 0$ it's $x$ so its derivative is $1$. For $x \leq 0$ it's $-x$ so its derivative is $-1$. But there's a problem. The derivative doesn't exist at $0$ because $1 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \neq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = -1$.

Comment: @aes: ok, by this argument then the function is differentiable evrywhere on $\Bbb R^{2}$ except at the origin $(0,0)$, is that right?

Comment: By what you've checked so far, you need to see if the derivatives agree on the $x$- and $y$-axes as well as at $(0,0)$.

Comment: No. Fix $y$ and try to check if $x\mapsto g(x,y)$ is differentiable at $x=0$. Then use symmetry to conclude where $g$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @aes: ok, by this argument then the function is differentiable evrywhere on $\Bbb R ^{2} except on lines $x=0$  and $y=0$, is that right?

Comment: Well, you should still check the derivatives to see if they agree on those lines --- as far as you've seen so far, they might or they might not. You need to check. Compute the "first quadrant" derivative at $(0,1)$ and compare it with the "second quadrant" derivative at $(0,1)$. If they agree, then it is differentiable at $(0,1)$, and if they don't, it isn't. (One-dimensional example, for reference: $x|x|$ is differentiable at $0$, with derivative equal to $0$ there.)